# Fetch Request Data is missing Data in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

For the past few weeks, I have been trying to send audio files to a server in flask using the fetch function. The code for the post request is as follows

```
    sendDataToServer = async (data, timecode, location = "postFileWebm/") => {
    // data is a blob
    // timecode is current time in millisecons
    // location is the function to run in the flask server
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", data);
    const length = data.length || data.size;
    console.log( formData.get( "file" ) );
    return fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/${location}`, {
        headers: {
            name: `${this.props.id}${timecode}`,
            segment: count,
            id: this.props.id,
            label: this.state.label,
            gameId: this.props.gameId,
            "Content-Length": length,
            extension: "wav",
            "Content-Range": "bytes " + 0 + "-" + length + "/" + length,
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary",
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    },);
};
```

In most devices the following code is functional and the request data is similar to

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybLCq4cl3vSy70eG4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: audio/wav

RIFF$@WAVEfmt »wdata@
------WebKitFormBoundarybLCq4cl3vSy70eG4--
```

but in iOS the same code is missing the data and is usually

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybLCq4cl3vSy70eG4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: audio/wav


------WebKitFormBoundarybLCq4cl3vSy70eG4--
```

Wanted to ask then if someone knew how to make this code function in iOS

Comment: Might not be a problem with the request itself, but with what you pass into this function as `data` in the first place …?

Comment: what I pass to the function as `data` is an audio blob coming from the microphone. I am able to download this blob and play the audio correctly